# `sort.Slice` order is non-deterministic

Tags: string, sorting, go, slice

I'm trying to use `sort.Slice` from the Go standard library to sort a slice of strings. I want them sorted alphabetically, **except** I want the empty string to appear after all other strings (hence I can't just use `sort.Strings`).

For the less function, I thought this would work:

```golang
func(i, j int) bool {
    return s[j] == "" || s[i] < s[j]
}
```

However, I seem to be getting random answers depending on what the input order is. Here's a MWE:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := []string{"", "foo", "bar", "baz"}

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    rand.Shuffle(len(s), func(i, j int) {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    })
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)

    sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
        return s[j] == "" || s[i] < s[j]
    })
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
}
```

and here's the output from running that a few times:

```
$ go run ./z
["" "foo" "baz" "bar"]
["bar" "baz" "foo" ""]
$ go run ./z
["baz" "" "foo" "bar"]
["bar" "" "baz" "foo"]
$ go run ./z
["bar" "foo" "" "baz"]
["" "bar" "baz" "foo"]
$ go run ./z
["bar" "foo" "baz" ""]
["" "bar" "baz" "foo"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your `less()` function isn't saying what you want it to say.

You said you want empty strings to be sorted after all non-empty strings. Your logic:

```
return s[j] == "" || s[i] < s[j]
```

This does tell if the second is `""`, then the first is less. This is more or less correct (except if both are empty, "is-less" is not really true: they are equal). But what if the first is `""` and the second isn't? Then your function should return `false` but instead it returns `s[i] < s[j]`. If the second isn't empty, this will be `true`, telling `""` is less than the other, exactly the opposite what you want.

The correct "is-less" relation is like this:

```
sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
    if s[j] == "" && s[i] != "" {
        return true
    }
    if s[i] == "" && s[j] != "" {
        return false
    }
    return s[i] < s[j]
})
```

If only the second is `""`, you want the first to be less. If only the first is empty, you want it "not be less". Else use normal order (which is byte-wise).

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ju-YV-DKZTJ).

Note that if both the first and second values would be empty, this function will return `false` because `""` is not less than `""` (they are equal). This is the proper value to return, although returning `true` here would still result in correct order (swapping empty elements would result in same result), but this may result in fewer swaps.

#### Transforming the logic using XOR

Note that in the custom logic there is deviation from the normal order if only one of the strings is empty. This is the [logical XOR (Exclusive OR) relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or): `a XOR b` is `true` if only `a` or only `b` is `true`. In Go there is no logical `XOR` operator, but `a XOR b` is equivalent to `a != b`.

If one empty string is "detected", the result is `true` if the second one is the empty (else `false`). So we could apply this identity transformation to our logic:

```
sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
    // Move empty elements to the end:
    if (s[i] == "") != (s[j] == "") { // If only one is empty
        return s[j] == ""
    }
    return s[i] < s[j]
})
```

This is shorter and probably more efficient, but as you can see, it's harder to understand. Use this only if performance does matter. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/CHCfbCRdatv).

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The comparison at the end will only ever compare two empty strings.

Comment: On second thought, the comparison is actually unreachable.

Comment: @Peter Oops, sorry, used the wrong operator. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I figured my "less" logic was probably wrong but couldn't quite see how.